# Why can't my FreeBSD 6.1 (vmware player client under Win7) do DNS in Bridged mode

Tags: windows-7, dns, freebsd, vmware-player

I have a **64-bit FreeBSD 6.1** client, running under **Windows 7 (64-bit)**  via **VMWare player 3.0**, with networking set to **bridge mode**.

DHCP goes fine on boot...   I get correct adress/gateway/nameserver info... I have good connectivity to the world in that I can ping any host I can name by IP addr, (including both of the nameservers in resolv.conf,) ...but I can't resolve any names.

Inside the Windows box, the network interface has **VMWare Bridge Protocol** enabled, and the windows side of things has full connectivity.

dig replies with:

*;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached*

...even if I use "dig @server_ip_addr" to point it at a pingable, working nameserver

If I set VM networking to NAT mode, I can get outbound connectivity (with happy DNS) but, of course, can't do INBOUND connectivity, which I need.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Might as well answer my own question in case someone else has a similar problem...

After much thrashing, I found out that it was related to the Shrewsoft VPN driver I was also running, which ran at startup whether or not I connected to the VPN. Updating to the 2.1.6 Beta driver caused my problem to go away.

Comment: I have the same problem with Windows XP, VMware player 3.1.4, and a guest running Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS Server, with networking set to bridged.  I went to Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Services, and  stopped the ShrewSoft DNS Proxy Daemon.  This fixed the guest DNS issue.  I upgraded to ShrewSoft 2.1.7, and I'm still seeing some strange behavior (it appears to work after connecting once, even if I then disconnect), but at least I now know where to look.  Thanks!